# cf organization Id retrieval in bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, organization

How do I find the organization Id from a cf node application on Bluemix (programmatically)?

I did not find a cf command that gives back the organization ID other than `cf target` but that returns too many lines - I just need the organization ID

What I did so far was to break the returned string to find the value I need but I'm hoping there is a better way...

Answer (score 1):

```
cf org orgname --guid
```

the command above gives you the guid for the org